# How do I use threading in a class?

Tags: c++, multithreading, opengl

I'm trying to create a loading screen for my OpenGL project and have read that to get it to work correctly it was best to use threading. I'm trying to call my function with my thread, but I keep getting these errors:

> error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 3 arguments
>
> IntelliSense: no instance of constructor "std::thread::thread" matches the argument list
>               argument types are: (void (Screen* newScreen, bool activeVisuals, bool activeControls), PlayScreen *, bool, bool)

This is my code:

```
//LoadingScreen
class LoadingScreen
{
    LoadingScreen();
    void LoadNewScreen(Screen* newScreen, bool activeVisuals, bool activeControls);
    void Setup();
};

void LoadingScreen::LoadNewScreen(Screen* newScreen, bool activeVisuals, bool activeControls)
{

}

void LoadingScreen::Setup()
{
    PlayScreen *playScreen = new PlayScreen();
    std::thread first(LoadingScreen::LoadNewScreen,playScreen, true, true);// , playScreen, true, true);

    first.join();
}

//source.cpp
LoadingScreen loadingScreen;
int main()
{
    LoadingScreen loadingScreen = LoadingScreen();
    loadingScreen.Setup();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Be sure you understand how threading plays with OpenGL when doing this. I don't know what kind of resources you are loading, but you may run into CPU/GPU synchronization issues if you use multiple render contexts that share resources or map/unmap buffer memory.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Yeah I seem to be having trouble getting things to work with threading. It keeps throwing exceptions that I can't find any information on like: Unhandled exception at 0x00E9E2C9 in [program name] 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000020.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass an additional parameter which is an instance of the class whose member function was passed as the first argument.

```
std::thread first(&LoadingScreen::LoadNewScreen, this, playScreen, true, true);
                                             //  ^^^^ <= instance of LoadingScreen
```

The additional parameter is needed because this is what actually calls `LoadNewScreen`.

```
this->LoadNewScreen(playScreen, true, true);
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well you don't necessarily need to pass a pointer but in this case, yes.

Comment: That got it to compile. Thank you for the answer. Why did it need the additional instance?

Comment: @WhyYouNoWork Because that's what calls **LoadNewScreen**. `this->LoadNewScreen(playScreen, true, true);`

Comment: I don't like the "additional instance" terminology in the answer; I think it misled WhyYouNoWork just there!

Answer (score 1):

You need to give `std::thread(Function &&f, Args&&... args)` a Lambda or a Function Pointer.

Change

```
std::thread first(LoadingScreen::LoadNewScreen,playScreen, true, true);
```

To

```
std::thread first(&LoadingScreen::LoadNewScreen,playScreen, true, true);
```

Or a Lambda if you need a reference to the `this` pointer.

Comment: I tried this before answering. It causes my first error that I listed